# Randomize numbers with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Is there a simple jQuery way to create numbers randomly showing then a number 1 -6 is choosing after a few seconds? [Like dice]

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This doesn't require jQuery. The JavaScript [`Math.random`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function returns a random number between 0 and 1, so if you want a number between 1 and 6, you can do:

```
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

**Update:** (as per comment) If you want to display a random number that changes every so often, you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to create a timer:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $('#my_div').text(number);
},
1000); // every 1 second
```

Comment: I know that, but I also need numbers 1- 6 to animate randomly.

Comment: Great! and after 5 seconds a random number 1- 6 is selected, how can I do that?

Comment: @omnix: Asking about random numbers and timers was a valid question, but what you're asking now suggests that you aren't familiar with JavaScript at all. You should start by reading a good tutorial or book.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need jQuery, just use javascript's [`Math.random`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function.

**edit**:
If you want to have a number from 1 to 6 show randomly every second, you can do something like this:

```
<span id="number"></span>

<script language="javascript">
  function generate() {
    $('#number').text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  }
  setInterval(generate, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function rollDice(){
   return (Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1);
}
```

Comment: That'll give you a number between 0 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a `random()` available.  Take a look at [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Coding in Perl,  I used the rand() function that generates the number at random and wanted only 1, 2, or 3 to be randomly selected. Due to Perl printing out the number one when doing "1 + " ...  so I also did a if else statement that if the number generated zero, run the function again, and it works like a charm.

printing out the results will always give a random number of either 1, 2, or 3.

That is just another idea and sure people will say that is newbie stuff but at the same time, I am a newbie but it works.  My issue was when printing out my stuff, it kept spitting out that 1 being used to start at 1 and not zero for indexing.